# How do I add weight to k-NN model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-modeling, knn, weighted

How do I add weight to certain fields that I'm using to predict `Outcome`? I'm using a k-NN model in this case.

I'm using library(class) but open to changing that if I need to.

The fields I'm using are either type integer or double and have already been normalized:
Pregnancies, Glucose, BMI, BloodPressure, SkinThickness, Insulin, DiabetesPedigreeFunction, & Age from the [Pima Diabetes Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database).

```
knn_predictions = test_knn_scaled %>% 
          mutate(Predict=knn(train=dplyr::select(train_knn_scaled, -Outcome),
                             test=dplyr::select(test_knn_scaled, -Outcome),
                             cl=factor(train_knn_scaled$Outcome,levels=c(0,1)),
                             k=which.max(accuracy_k)))
```